# How do I selectively add parts of one project to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import

I want the following items in this solution to be added to another solution:

[image: Try to export]

(the selected items are what I want to import)

I select those items, and right click > copy, but when I go to paste the items, I can't paste anything:

[image: Unable to paste]

Is it possible to import just allowed.cs, theme.cs, theme2.cs, themebase.cs to EmailSpitter? I also want to copy everything in Allowed.cs (meaning the design and the code inside)

I tried moving the items one at a time, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it's a better idea to pull those into a class library, and add a reference to it from both projects.

This will allow you to share the same code, without duplication.  This is much nicer to maintain over time, as you only have the code in one place, so you can fix your issues in a single place.

Comment: That's a good idea, but this is just the trial portion of the code I'm writing - I don't want it to update, I just want to be able to copy the code into this without having to redesign it all, copy all the code, etc..

Comment: @chipperyman573 You just have to copy one file at a time.  You can't copy and paste in bulk.

Comment: Even when I just copy one file, I still can't paste it.

Comment: Reed's advice is honestly the best .... put these modules into their own class library and reference that project.